# Frechet Derivative of operator

Tags: frechet-derivative

I'm using Frechet derivative to get derivative of operator

$$
{\mathbf{F}}{'_{ij}}\left( {{{\mathbf{U}}^{\left( k \right)}}} \right)\delta {U_j} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to 0} \frac{{{F_i}\left( {{{\mathbf{U}}^{\left( k \right)}} + \eta \delta {U_j}} \right) - {F_i}\left( {{{\mathbf{U}}^{\left( k \right)}}} \right)}}{\eta }
$$

The function in question is this
$$
F_2(u,v)=\frac{\varepsilon }{{qN{\mu _n}}}\left( {{e^{u - v}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {u - v} \right) + \frac{{{e^{u - v}} }}{{{\tau _n}}}} \right) - \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left\{ {{e^{u - v}}\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}}} \right\}
$$

And the frechet derivative I want is
$$
F_2'(u)\delta u
$$

Here is what i did
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to 0} \frac{{\frac{\varepsilon }{{qN{\mu _n}}}\left( {{e^{u + \eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}} - v}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {u + \eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}} - v} \right) + \frac{{{e^{u + \eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}} - v}}}}{{{\tau _n}}}} \right) - \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left\{ {{e^{u + \eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}} - v}}\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}}} \right\} - \frac{\varepsilon }{{qN{\mu _n}}}\left( {{e^{u - v}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {u - v} \right) + \frac{{{e^{u - v}}}}{{{\tau _n}}}} \right) + \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left\{ {{e^{u - v}}\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}}} \right\}}}{\eta }
$$
$$
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to 0} \frac{{\frac{\varepsilon }{{qN{\mu _n}}}\left( {{e^{u - v}}\left\{ {{e^{\eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}}}}\left[ {\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {u - v} \right) + \frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {\eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}}} \right)} \right] - \frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {u - v} \right)} \right\} + \frac{{{e^{u + \eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}} - v}}}}{{{\tau _n}}} - \frac{{{e^{u - v}}}}{{{\tau _n}}}} \right) - \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left\{ {{e^{u + \eta \delta {u^{\left( k \right)}} - v}}\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}}} \right\} + \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left\{ {{e^{u - v}}\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}}} \right\}}}{\eta }
$$
$$
 = \frac{\varepsilon }{{qN{\mu _n}}}{e^{u - v}}\left\{ {\delta {u^{\left( k \right)}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {u - v} \right) + \frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {\delta {u^{\left( k \right)}}} \right) + \frac{{\delta {u^{\left( k \right)}}}}{{{\tau _n}}}} \right\} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left\{ {{e^{u - v}}\delta {u^{\left( k \right)}}\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}}} \right\}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You need to specify a normed space and what the function is.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to define function. Normed space? why do i need to define normed space?

Comment: Because the Fréchet derivative is defined in terms of a norm.